# Mathematical foundation crisis and the RSA

Tags: number-theory, math-history, cryptography

I am currently in my last year of high school and I am writing a report on cryptography from a idea historical and mathematical perspective.

I am including a few of the subjects: Cantor's diagonal proof, Russel's evidence against cardinal sets, Hilbert's list of 23, Gödel's incompleteness theorem, Turing machines, p=np and some kind of encryption like RSA.

I am just thinking about how to explain the RSA in the context of the other subjects. How did the mathematical foundation crisis affect modern cryptography, did it give birth to it?

I have looked for how they are connected and read a lot of idea historical and mathematical texts on the subject but I can't seem to find the connection.

Well I hope I asked in the right place for this :)

Comment: From my immediate perspective they are completely disjoint subject with no connection to speak of. Except in the incidental sense that the foundational work in the early 1900s led to the formalization of computability, which (arguably?) led to computers, which led to new challenges for cryptography.

Comment: I don't know that there is a connection. There is no need to know anything about foundations to understand RSA, and I doubt that the papers proposing RSA made any mention of foundational issues. Godel & Turing showed there are problems you can't solve at all (that's a *very* loose interpretation of their work), while cryptography is concerned with problems that you can't solve efficiently.

Comment: Well I see, I will try to direct my focus somewhere else.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What crisis? In the early 20th century, mathematics had a period of explosive growth.

Comment: @Reindeernix: Did you read this wonderful paper by the authors of RSA? http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf . Also, you might want to include a truer history of http://cryptome.org/ukpk-alt.htm, and it was probably known before that too! I am not sure mixing these things is good IMO. Regards